# How do I stream a SOAP body of encoded XML from requests into lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, python-requests

I'm receiving XML as the payload of a SOAP response from [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), i.e. the data looks about like this:

```
<!-- the rest of the SOAP envelope -->
<soap:Body>
    <ActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <ActionResult>
            &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
            &lt;RunAction&gt;
                &lt;DataElement&gt;data&lt;/DataElement&gt;
            &lt;/RunAction&gt;
        </ActionResult>
    </ActionResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

The data I'm interested in is the content of the `<ActionResult>` element and what I want to effectively parse is basically this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunAction>
    <DataElement>data</DataElement>
</RunAction>
```

Now I would like to use lxml's `iterparse()` to parse this inner XML.

How do I do this in a (peak) memory efficient manner? I already have a fast iter function, and of course I would like to use requests' [raw](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) data stream with `stream=True`.

But first I need to
a) extract the XML payload from the `<ActionResult>` element and
b) unescape the escaped XML.

How do I do this 'filtering', i.e. without duplicating more than necessary in memory? To emphasize, I care less about CPU cycles right now, but I want to hold as little bytes as possible parallel in memory.

I assume I have to write a file-like object which responds to lxml's `read()` calls and takes the data from requests' `raw` stream. What's the minimal interface I need to implement. Is there anything I can use e.g. for the buffering, so I don't have to write my own ring buffer? Any base code I can build on top of? This feels so much like reinventing a (non-trivial) wheel…